# Powershell - include Get-Date in .log file inside the Add-Content Cmdlet

Tags: powershell, logging, time

I've made a small Powershell Script which deletes alle files and folders except specific ones. 
The script itself works pretty good but I have a lot of troubble getting the logging to work. I'm currently on a good way with the `Add-Content` Cmdlet which works good. The only thing I now want to include is a small `Get-Date` Cmdlet inside the `Add-Content` which also includes the current time in the log when the specific file/folder was deleted. But I just can't get it to work properly. Can someone help me?

Here is what I got so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\sample\*\notesdata' -Recurse -exclude names.nsf |
Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
Where {$_ -notlike 'C:\sample\*\notesdata\Roaming*'} |
Where {$_ -notlike 'C:\sample\*\notesdata\Archive*'} |
sort length -Descending |
Remove-Item -force -Recurse -Verbose 4>&1 | Add-Content -Path .\ergebnis.log, .\ergebnis2.log -Value (Get-Date)
```

The file "names.nsf" and the folders "Roaming", "Archive" will not get deleted.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is the current result and how does your expected result look like?

Comment: Either you pipe something to `Add-Content` or you provide it with the parameter `-Value`. Es geht nicht beides gleichzeitig. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Olaf I'm guessing you're getting error like:

> Add-Content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for
>   the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or
>   the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that
>   take pipeline input.

If you want to date the output for logging purposes you could add something a `ForEach-Object` before the `Add-Content` command.  Something like:

```
Remove-Item C:\temp\something.txt -Verbose 4>&1 | ForEach-Object{ "$(Get-Date -format g) : $($_)" } | Add-Content C:\temp\something2.txt
```

Let us know if that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Thats exactly what I was looking for the whole time. Thanks a lot!